# Relationships on attribute level in Enterprise Architect

Tags: attributes, uml, modeling, class-diagram, enterprise-architect

I am looking for the best solution to draw mapping diagram in EA. I find that composite structure diagram might suits my needs. I have even found good example of such diagram on the net:

[image: Original source: http://www.dthomas.co.uk/dtalm/images/eshot/test/data_map.JPG]
(Original source: http://www.dthomas.co.uk/dtalm/images/eshot/test/data_map.JPG)

This diagram was fully created in EA (as author claims). However I am not able to attach 'represents' relation to the attribute. Does any one know how to do that (I am talking about those little open squares in class representations).

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good question!
I found your answer [in Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sparx-enterprise-architect-general/aAa6SgxQbws):

> draw a dependency from one class to the other.
>
> Then Right Click on the left side of the dependency and chose Link to Element Feature, chose Attribut and then select your attribute.
>
> On the right side the same procedure.

On my EA 10 (Corp.Ed.), I was able to reproduce the described steps. See attached image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded EA and created a simple example by creating :

- one class with a part
- one collaboration with also a part
- one  'represents' relation by using the command highlighted [image: here]

Hoping it helps,

EBR.

PS: it is out of the scope of your question but what is the goal of this mapping diagram? It is just curiosity..

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not the case. Look at the linked picture. I would like to have relation on the attribute level. The property is 'part' not attribute. The goal is to represent mappings between two system for migration purposes.

Comment: observer give you the right answer (I tested it :-)).
I just would highlight the fact that SysML with this Block diagrams and allocations could better fit to your purpose. It is really close to your solution but it has a clear semantic (I do not know what EA represent stereotype means), EA support it (as a lot of other tools) and it is pretty standard.